# Having trouble with clojure macro

Tags: macros, clojure

I'm trying to write a macro that I can use to call a function on a new thread and print the name of the function as well as the name of the thread after running it.

So far what I have is:

```
     (defmacro start-threads [f]
        '(let [t (Thread. 'f)]
            (prn (str "running " 'f " on: " (.getName t)))))
```

which when I run:

```
    (start-threads funcname)
```

outputs: "running f on: Thread-47". and I would like it to output: "running funcname on: Thread-47. When I try unquoting it it try's to evaluate the function. I know I haven't run .start on the thread here, but I should be able to add that in afterward. I'm sure a macro isnt completely necessary here, I'm mostly wondering out of curiosity as I am just starting to wrap my mind around how macros in clojure work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, what you want is syntax-quote rather than normal quote.

```
(defmacro start-threads [f]
  `(let [t# (Thread. ~f)]
    (prn (str "running " '~f " on: " (.getName t#)))))
```

`~f` in a syntax-quote interpolates the value of `f`, `'~f` quotes that value and the `t#` makes an auto-gensym so the variable name won't conflict with any surrounding names.

But as you correctly note, you really don't need a macro for this. It could easily be a function:

```
(defn start-threads [f]
  (let [t (Thread. f)]
    (prn (str "running " f " on: " (.getName t)))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely helpful. I guess one thing I wanted is instead of getting a string representation of the function, which looks like data_staging.main$write_thread@52a731cb, I wanted the actual text that I types in as the argument to the macro. so (start-thread write-thread) would output "running write-thread on: Thread-47". Clearly not a big deal, I'm just curious how this could be done.

Comment: @SeanGeoffreyPietz: Ah, I see. OK, I've changed the code to work that way. The only difference is that you just need to quote the second `~f`. And that *is* something that you need a macro to do, because arguments will be evaluated before the function they're passed to executes.